# LESS CSS naming convention - Child selectors on hover

Tags: css, hover, less

In LESS, you can reference a child selector as follows:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="button-text"> Text </div>
</div>

.button {
  &-text {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
.button .button-text { color:red; }
```

This is neat and ideal, however, when using a hover, is there a way to maintain the same / similar syntax for the child element? Currently, this wouldn't naturally work:

```
.button {
  &:hover {
    &-text {
      color:red;
    }
  }
}
```

This won't work and as expected, outputs something along the lines of

```
.button:hover .hover-text { }
```

Is there a way to get the expected hover result without defining the full class name, in this instance ".button-text"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the parents selector `&` represents all parent selectors (not just the nearest ancestor), nesting under hover, will always include the `:hover` text.

This rule:

```
.button {
  &:hover &-text {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Will provide the result ([lessismore playgroud](http://lesscssismore.com/f34hla/1)):

```
.button:hover .button-text {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ori, Thank you for the response. What about when the button has styles on hover, such as this:

.button {
  &:hover {
    background:green;
    &-text {
      color:red;
    }
  } 
}

Is there a way to cater for the button and the text individually also?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to declare them separately:
.button {
  &:hover &-text {
    color:red;
  }
&:hover { background:green; } }, but I'll be happy to be wrong :)